# Why does the dynamically created fields in a form not pass when submitted?

Tags: javascript

Dynamically created select elements (form fields) does not get sent when form is submitted.

added the element to the form.objects array

```
var selectHeads = ['first','second'];
function orderFill(firstSelect){ 
var base = firstSelect.id.split('-');
++base[1];
var sel = document.createElement('select');
sel.id = base[0] + '-' + base[1];
sel.name = sel.id;

var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = orderHeads[0];
opt.innerHTML = orderHeads[0];
sel.appendChild(opt);

var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = orderHeads[1];
opt.innerHTML = orderHeads[1];
sel.appendChild(opt);

firstSelectfirstSelect.parentNode.appendChild(sel);
document.mainform.elements.push(sel);
document.getElementById(base[0] + '-' + 
base[1]).setAttribute('onchange','orderFill(this)');
}
```

When the first select is changed a second select is created.  When it's changed a third is created.  When submitted, the second select selected data is sent to be processed.

Comment: `firstSelectfirstSelect.parentNode.appendChild(sel);` Typo?

Comment: form elements need a name attribute so the form knows how to call that value